# Unable to get repr for <class 'doctr.models.predictor.tensorflow.OCRPredictor>

Tags: python, computer-vision, ocr, tensorflow2.0

I am using DoCTR OCR for Optical Character recognition. But for a few days, I was stuck due to the above exception while initializing the pre-trained models which are provided by the DoCTR.

This is my source code.

```
try:
    from doctr.models import ocr_predictor
    model = ocr_predictor(pretrained=True)
    result = model([aligned_image])
    json_output = result.export()
except Exception as e:
    self.logger.exception("Exception :" + str(e))
```

When I started to debug it, it throws the above exception while initializing the model.

[image]

I couldn't find how the above error occurred and a way to solve it. After handling the exception with try-except block it throws an exception like
`ValueError: Tensor("Const_1:0", shape=(3,), dtype=float32) must be from the same graph as Tensor("stack:0", shape=(1, 1024, 1024, 3), dtype=float32) (graphs are <tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Graph object at 0x7f7a8cd8ee50> and <tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Graph object at 0x7f7a180613d0>)` .(reference documentation : https://mindee.github.io/doctr/).

Comment: This issue has been solved after clearing the backend sessions with `tf.keras.backend.clear_session()` . When we are creating many models in a loop, this global state will consume an increasing amount of memory over time. `clear_session()` releases the global state which helps to avoid clutter from old models and layers, especially when memory is limited

Comment: https://github.com/mindee/doctr/discussions/916